# How to open and display a PDF file using Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qt4

I am trying to open and read a PDF file using Qt, but there is no specific way to do that.

Comment: At some point this may get added to Qt WebEngine - see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50556

Answer (score 5):

Qt itself does not include PDF reading/rendering functionality as far as I know. You might want to have a look at [libpoppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) which has Qt bindings.

Comment: poppler use Xpdf, under GPL2 license. I love GPL but be care to do not use it in proprietary software.

Answer (score 3):

I found this very interesting article on [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_PDF) - "Handling PDF - Qt Project".
This page discusses various available options for working with PDF documents in a Qt application. The page does not exactly show how to "open and display an existing PDF document" but it can help you deduce something useful out of all that is explained there.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_PDF#a6e8f9aed2ac6481dc25a18a33342d03), the page says:

> For rendering pages or elements from existing PDF documents to image
>   files or in-memory pixmaps (useful e.g. for thumbnail generation or
>   implementing custom viewers), third-party libraries can be used (for
>   example: poppler-qt4 (freedesktop.org) and muPDF (mupdf.com)).
>
> Alternatively, the task can be delegated to existing command-line
>   tools (like poppler-utils (freedesktop.org) and muPDF (mupdf.com)).

Answer (score 2):

### As of Qt 5.10

Check out the [QPdfDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfdocument.html) Class. This class can open a PDF and you can use the [render](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfdocument.html#render) function to render a page to an image. I use the [QQuickPaintedItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html) to then "draw" this image but I am sure there are more ways to handle the [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) output.

### Prior to Qt 5.10

I used [libpoppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) to do a VERY similar process.
`#include <poppler/qt5/poppler-qt5.h>`
Use the [Poppler::Document](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/qt5/classPoppler_1_1Document.html) Class to load and handle the entire PDF document and look at the [Poppler::Page::renderToImage](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/qt5/classPoppler_1_1Page.html#ab9971eb1d8c4f437a95532b216e85e79) function to output the page as a [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : it is not supported in the Qt API.

Other answer : you can code it, I suggest you have a look at [this Qt application](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/GraphicsViewEdit+Layer?content=80234) which uses Ghostscript

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to open a pdf is using QProcess in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [okular](https://api.kde.org/okular/html/index.html) for pdf proccessing.